# Android - Passing .class to AsyncTask for use with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, android-asynctask

My app using is web based and uses Json for most of the communication. I am in the process of optimization of the code and ran into some problems.

Previously, all my activities used separate subclasses of AsyncTask to make calls to webservices, they got the response as a String and then parse it as Json and finally use the Gson fromJson() method to make the Java objects.

I'm trying to narrow it down to a single class that can be used by all. Currently, I have the following for my doInBackground()..

```
@Override
protected JsonObject doInBackground(Object... params) {

    String res = WebServices.httpGet(params[0]., (Map<String, String>) params[1]);
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jsonObject = parser.parse(res);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

So I pass as parameters a String that is the method to be called and a HashMap that has the parameters. The calling Activity then parse the Json as Java object using Gson.

However, since some of the responses may be pretty large, I don't want the Json to be parsed in the UI thread but rather in the AsyncTask. In order to do that I somehow need to pass the T.class parameter to my doInBackground() method because the Gson().fromJson() method requires it. My call would be something like

```
new AsyncJsonTask().execute("GetValues", parameterMap, POJO.class);
```

How can I accomplish this and is this the correct approach to minimization here ?

Comment: But how do I get the POJO.class as an object ?? From the (Object... params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class<?>` is a subtype of `Object`, so you should be able to pass it as is.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing... I could have sworn I was getting a class casting error which is why I asked the question. Must have not built the project or something.

Comment: I had done a workaround already by passing the Class<?> through the AsyncTask object constructor. One other thing... since the AsyncTask will be used for just about any operation in the app, do you think it would be advantageous to make the class static so that a new instance doesn't have to be called each time.